# How does SCons build content signature about a function?

Tags: signature, scons

Recently I used SCons to build project. But it rebuild everytime.. After reading .sconsign.dblite file, I found that SCons will create a content signature for a function. Like this:

```
TargetA.txt: 99bb021f789f7bb1c23935daffecfb8e 1598528466 22769
        31aada685dfb3c4e5d1e474ba5cc251d [buildfunction(target, source, env)]
```

It create a signature for function `buildfunction(target, source, env)` which created file `TargetA.txt`. But I couldn't find the relative code. I think it's offered by SCons. Can anyone give me a help?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to go look at the source code.
It's fairly complicated.

Starts here:
https://github.com/SCons/scons/blob/master/SCons/Action.py#L1210

Also subject to change.
We may revamp in the not to distant future as python 3.5+ has features which may simplify the logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The version of SCons we used is old, and its guide says supporting py3.5+. If I run it in Py3.6 it would rebuild the whole project. This seems the only way to solve the question..

Comment: Yes. The CHANGES.txt and RELEASE notes for 3.0.0 also indicate that switching python versions from 2.7 -> 3.5+ will most likely cause a full rebuild.  Try updating to latest 4.0.1

Comment: Thanks. And one more question: I found the reason for rebuilding was because SCons added all the addresses of functions called by ```buildfunction()`` under Py 3.6. Is it possible to stop this behavior, or change this output information?

Comment: Please bring your issue with and example to the users mailing list or our discord channel. See here: https://scons.org/contact.html

Comment: Also note scons --debug=explain can help explain why things rebuild.. (you've already dug past that, but for future reference)